# Why do some languages use a flipped Y axis?

Tags: java, axis

In Actionscript and 3D systems, the Y axis increases upwards (bottom is either 0 or -1, and top is usually 1). This convention makes sense relative to the real world. However in languages such as Java, the convention is flipped (bottom is 1, and top is 0 or -1). I've always wondered: Why?

Thanks! :)

Comment: "the real world" ? You mean some conventions used in Physics ? There is no arrow pointing towards the sky in the real world.

Comment: When you read a book in English, horizontal flows to the right, vertical flows downside. Hence the coordinates (e.g. used in X11).

Comment: This top to bottom direction was yet present in the age of cathodic screens.

Answer (score 6):

In 2D software, the y-direction is typically downwards - top left corner of the screen is the origin. The first screens were text only, and you would number text lines from the top. This numbering system stuck.

In 3D software, many libraries choose to implement Y as up, but only because, as you've mentioned, that "makes more sense".

This is not a feature of the "language". It's a feature of the library.

Comment: I stand corrected, but I was wondering why the convention exists for 2D libraries--that the origin should be top left and that y counts down the screen positively.

Comment: @Yippers: The convention came from the convention for numbering lines of text. Line 2 comes below Line 1 for text. Why change your numbering system when you switch to pixels?